# How to aggregate data between parent and subsite lists?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a Parent Site List and Sub Site list, where I need to get data from multi-choice checkbox column box, convert it to a string and copy it to a list on a sub site.

Is there way to do this programmatically with SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with programming. In SharePoint Online, you can use **Java Script Client Object Model**. Check dis MSDN link to see a lot of examples:

[How to: Complete basic operations using JavaScript library code in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj163201.aspx)

Comment: Can this be used via web part or does this have to be used in an App Model?

Comment: Yes, you can include JavaScript code inside a Content Edit Web Part. Very simple: http://sharepointadam.com/2010/08/31/insert-javascript-into-a-content-editor-web-part-cewp/